# Triggering a second GraphQL query based on data from initial query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, hasura

**Overview**

When `WrappedApp` initially loads, a query is sent to the GraphQL API to fetch the data (Tags).

After this has completed a user can add an item to the `ShortList` in `WrappedApp` by clicking on a Tag in the `TagsList` (see screenshot below).

**Question**

How can I get this click of a Tag in the `TagsList` (i.e. security was clicked in the example below) to trigger the second GraphQL query named `GQLSIMILARTAGS` and render the result above the `ShortList` components data or at least console.log the result of the `GQLSIMILARTAGS` query?  `GQLSIMILARTAGS` accepts a variable which would be the Tag that was clicked and added to `ShortList`.

[image: shortlist]

**What have I tried?**

I tried modifying the `addFavourite` function in `WrappedApp` to call `GQLFunc` with the new `GQLSIMILARTAGS` query with `useQuery(GQLSIMILARTAGS)` but this may not be the best approach.

This is the Apollo GraphQL query code.

```
graphclient.js




const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://xxxx.herokuapp.com/v1/graphql",
});

const GQLTAGS = gql`
  {
    tag(
      order_by: { tag_related_counts_aggregate: { count: desc } }
      where: { label: { _nin: ["None", "null"] } }
    ) {
      id
      label
      tag_related_counts_aggregate {
        aggregate {
          count
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

        const GQLSIMILARTAGS = gql`
  query {
    tag(
      where: { tag_related_counts: { search_label: { _eq: "security" } } }
      distinct_on: id
    ) {
      label
      tag_related_counts {
        count
        other_label
        search_label
      }
    }
  }
`;

function GQLFunc(props) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQLTAGS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  let CallingApp = props.callingApp;
  if (data) return <CallingApp data={data.tag} />;
}

export { client, GQLTAGS, GQLFunc };
```

This is the main `WrappedApp.js` App (edit: Updated to function component as per @xadm feedback).

```
       function WrappedApp(props) {
  const [filterText, setfilterText] = useState("");
  const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);

  // update filterText in state when user types
  const filterUpdate = (value) => {
    setfilterText(value);
  };

  // add clicked name ID to the favourites array
  const addFavourite = (id) => {
    const newSet = favourites.concat([id]);
    setFavourites(newSet);
  };

  // remove ID from the favourites array
  const deleteFavourite = (id) => {
    //console.log(id);
    const newList = [...favourites.slice(0, id), ...favourites.slice(id + 1)];
    setFavourites(newList);
  };

  const hasSearch = filterText.length > 0;
  return (
    <div>
      {GQLSimilarFunc()}
      <header>
        <Greeting />
        <Search filterVal={filterText} filterUpdate={filterUpdate} />
      </header>
      <main>
        <ShortList
          data={props.data}
          favourites={favourites}
          simfunc={GQLSimilarFunc}
        />

        <TagsList
          data={props.data}
          filter={filterText}
          favourites={favourites}
          addFavourite={addFavourite}
        />
        {/* 
            Show only if user has typed in search.
            To reset the input field, we pass an 
            empty value to the filterUpdate method
          */}
        {hasSearch && (
          <button onClick={() => filterUpdate("")}> Clear Search</button>
        )}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default WrappedApp;
```

Other code used in `WrappedApp`

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { GQLSimilarFunc } from "./graphclient";

/* ############################ */
/* ##### Single tag ##### */
/* ############################ */

const Tag = ({ id, info, handleFavourite }) => (
  <li className={info.count} onClick={() => handleFavourite(id)}>
    {info.label} ({info.tag_related_counts_aggregate.aggregate.count})
  </li>
);


/* ##################### */
/* ##### Shortlist ##### */
/* ##################### */

const ShortList = ({ favourites, data, simfunc }) => {
  const hasFavourites = favourites.length > 0;
  const favList = favourites.map((fav, i) => {
    console.log(data.find((tag) => tag.id === fav).label);
    return (
      <Tag
        id={i}
        key={i}
        info={data.find((tag) => tag.id === fav)}
        //handleFavourite={(id) => deleteFavourite(id)}
        handleFavourite={() => simfunc()}
        /*handleFavourite={GQLSimilarFunc(
          data.find((tag) => tag.id === fav).label
        )}*/
      />
    );
  });
  //console.log(data.find((tag) => tag.id === 4436));

  return (
    <div className="favourites">
      <h4>
        {hasFavourites
          ? "Shortlist. Click to remove.."
          : "Click on a tag to shortlist it.."}
      </h4>
      <ul>{favList}</ul>
      {hasFavourites && <hr />}
    </div>
  );
};

/* ########################### */
/* ##### Tag list ##### */
/* ########################### */

const TagsList = ({ data, filter, favourites, addFavourite }) => {
  const input = filter;

  // Gather list of tags
  const tags = data
    // filtering out the tags that...
    .filter((tag, i) => {
      return (
        // ...are already favourited
        favourites.indexOf(tag.id) === -1 &&
        // ...are not matching the current search value
        !tag.label.indexOf(input)
      );
    })
    // ...output a <Name /> component for each name
    .map((tag, i) => {
      //console.log(tag.label);
      // only display tags that match current input string
      return (
        <Tag
          id={tag.id}
          key={i}
          info={tag}
          handleFavourite={(id) => addFavourite(id)}
        />
      );
    });

  /* ##### the component's output ##### */
  return <ul>{tags}</ul>;
};

/* ###################### */
/* ##### Search bar ##### */
/* ###################### */

// need a component class here
// since we are using `refs`
class Search extends Component {
  render() {
    const { filterVal, filterUpdate } = this.props;
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref="filterInput"
          placeholder="Type to filter.."
          // binding the input value to state
          value={filterVal}
          onChange={() => {
            filterUpdate(this.refs.filterInput.value);
          }}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my `index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { client, GQLTags, GQLFunc } from "./graphclient";
import WrappedApp from "./WrappedApp";

/* ############################ */
/* ##### Single tag ##### */
/* ############################ */

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <GQLFunc callingApp={WrappedApp} />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: if queries are parent-child related then use parent-child components - just inject another component level between GQLFunc and CallingApp.

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as

```
function GQLFunc(props) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQLTAGS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  //let CallingApp = props.callingApp;
  //if (data) return <CallingApp data={data.tag} />;
  if (data) return <GQLChild dataTag={data.tag} callingApp={props.callingApp} />;
}

function GQLChild(props) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQLSIMILARTAGS, {
    variables: {
      someSimilarRequiredVariableFromTagQueryResult: props.dataTag.something
    }
  });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  let CallingApp = props.callingApp;
  // pass data separately or combine into one `data` prop
  if (data) return <CallingApp dataSimilar={data} dataTag={props.dataTag} />;
}
```

Comment: Wrapping some ready app with a new data source is OK. Building next complexity 'above' App and searching for workarounds to pass next data/handlers from/to queries is **definitely not OK**. It is possible (context or apollo local state) BUT IT IS NOT THE RIGHT WAY. Rebuild your app using queries and mutations in the right places (inside app components).

Comment: Convert `<WrappedApp />` into functional component, use `useQuery` inside, pass `filterText` as query variable .... but (to avoid other problems/complexity) you should pass one/main variable - `where` complex condition object constructed using `filterText` value) .... `useMutation` (for add favourite mutation) can be placed in `<WrappedApp />` but also in `<TagsList/>` (no need to pass `addFavourite` handler) ... it all depends - where data fetched/rendered/updated

Comment: Even if it is a POC then you shouldn't go further in this direction, it will overcomplicate simple things. “Fail Fast, Succeed Faster”

Comment: I have converted `WrappedApp` to a function component and updated the code in the question.  Can you please show me what to do next?

Comment: assuming starting situation, where wrapper `<GQLFunc/>` reads tags and renders `<CallingApp data={data.tag} />` .... you have tags as `props.data` .... next ... `useQuery(GQLSIMILARTAGS)` (hardcoded now) in `<WrappedApp />` ... it will fetch some `data` with similar items ... you can pass into some child component.

Comment: Hi @xadm. I have updated the code in the question. `GQLSIMILARTAGS` is hard coded without variables and I am trying to trigger `GQLSimilarFunc `  in  `ShortList ` to send second query for similar tags.  If I can get this working I would add variables later.  Is it possible look at the updated code and tell me how to correct it as I think syntax when calling `ShortList` is incorrect.

Comment: what is it? function/component/handler? why do you need it? just use `useQuery` where you need

Comment: sorry I don't understand how I would use `useQuery`.   I modified the existing `deleteFavourite` in `ShortList` as I thought I could use it to click on shortlist entry and send for related tags.  Could you please show me how `useQuery` would work?

Comment: just like I wrote ... don't go further before this ... standard useQuery usage

Comment: `const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQLSIMILARTAGS);` in `<WrappedApp />` .. pass `data` to any child you want/need