# Converting React Class Component to a Function Component

Tags: reactjs

As per feedback from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62266428/triggering-a-second-graphql-query-based-on-data-from-initial-query) question.  I'm trying to convert this `WrappedApp`  class component to a function component.

This is the existing (working) class component:

```
class WrappedApp extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          filterText: "",
          favourites: [],
        };
      }

      // update filterText in state when user types
      filterUpdate(value) {
        this.setState({
          filterText: value,
        });
      }

      // add clicked name ID to the favourites array
      addFavourite(id) {
        const newSet = this.state.favourites.concat([id]);
        this.setState({
          favourites: newSet,
        });
      }

      // remove ID from the favourites array
      deleteFavourite(id) {
        const { favourites } = this.state;
        const newList = [...favourites.slice(0, id), ...favourites.slice(id + 1)];
        this.setState({
          favourites: newList,
        });
      }

      render() {
        const hasSearch = this.state.filterText.length > 0;
        return (
          <div>
            <header>
              <Greeting />
              <Search
                filterVal={this.state.filterText}
                filterUpdate={this.filterUpdate.bind(this)}
              />
            </header>
            <main>
              <ShortList
                data={this.props.data}
                favourites={this.state.favourites}
                deleteFavourite={this.deleteFavourite.bind(this)}
              />

              <TagsList
                data={this.props.data}
                filter={this.state.filterText}
                favourites={this.state.favourites}
                addFavourite={this.addFavourite.bind(this)}
              />
              {/* 
                Show only if user has typed in search.
                To reset the input field, we pass an 
                empty value to the filterUpdate method
              */}
              {hasSearch && (
                <button onClick={this.filterUpdate.bind(this, "")}>
                  Clear Search
                </button>
              )}
            </main>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default WrappedApp;
```

This code is used/referenced in the `WrappedApp` component and the new functional component:

```
const Tag = ({ id, info, handleFavourite }) => (
  <li className={info.count} onClick={() => handleFavourite(id)}>
    {info.label} ({info.tag_related_counts_aggregate.aggregate.count})
  </li>
);
const ShortList = ({ favourites, data, deleteFavourite }) => {
  const hasFavourites = favourites.length > 0;
  const favList = favourites.map((fav, i) => {
    return (
      <Tag
        id={i}
        key={i}
        info={data.find((tag) => tag.id === fav)}
        handleFavourite={(id) => deleteFavourite(id)}
      />
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="favourites">
      <h4>
        {hasFavourites
          ? "Shortlist. Click to remove.."
          : "Click on a tag to shortlist it.."}
      </h4>
      <ul>{favList}</ul>
      {hasFavourites && <hr />}
    </div>
  );
};


const TagsList = ({ data, filter, favourites, addFavourite }) => {
  const input = filter;

  // Gather list of tags
  const tags = data
    // filtering out the tags that...
    .filter((tag, i) => {
      return (
        // ...are already favourited
        favourites.indexOf(tag.id) === -1 &&
        // ...are not matching the current search value
        !tag.label.indexOf(input)
      );
    })
    // ...output a <Name /> component for each name
    .map((tag, i) => {
      // only display tags that match current input string
      return (
        <Tag
          id={tag.id}
          key={i}
          info={tag}
          handleFavourite={(id) => addFavourite(id)}
        />
      );
    });

  /* ##### the component's output ##### */
  return <ul>{tags}</ul>;
};


// need a component class here
// since we are using `refs`
class Search extends Component {
  render() {
    const { filterVal, filterUpdate } = this.props;
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref="filterInput"
          placeholder="Type to filter.."
          // binding the input value to state
          value={filterVal}
          onChange={() => {
            filterUpdate(this.refs.filterInput.value);
          }}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my initial unsuccessful attempt to convert the `WrappedApp` class component to a function component:

```
function WrappedApp(props) {
  const [filterText, setfilterText] = useState("");
  const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);

  // update filterText in state when user types
  const filterUpdate = (value) => {
    setfilterText(value);
  };

  // add clicked name ID to the favourites array
  const addFavourite = (id) => {
    const newSet = favourites.concat([id]);
    setFavourites(favourites);
  };

  // remove ID from the favourites array
  const deleteFavourite = (id) => {
    const newList = [...favourites.slice(0, id), ...favourites.slice(id + 1)];
    setFavourites(newList);
  };

  const hasSearch = filterText.length > 0;
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <Greeting />
        <Search filterVal filterUpdate />
      </header>
      <main>
        <ShortList data={props.data} favourites deleteFavourite />

        <TagsList
          data={props.data}
          filter={filterText}
          favourites
          addFavourite
        />
        {/* 
            Show only if user has typed in search.
            To reset the input field, we pass an 
            empty value to the filterUpdate method
          */}
        {hasSearch && <button onClick={filterUpdate}>Clear Search</button>}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default WrappedApp;
```

**What error am I seeing?**

Initial issue I am encountering is the `TypeError: favourites.map is not a function` error message.

Comment: when you say unsuccessful, why was it so?

Comment: Instead of showing conversion, show us  the relevant part of code that you're stuck.

Comment: @RedBaron I updated the question.  Initial issue I am encountering is the `TypeError: favourites.map is not a function` error message.

Comment: @ade1e see answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your error in the comment,

Instead of this:

```
<ShortList data={props.data} favourites deleteFavourite />
```

Use this:

```
<ShortList data={props.data} 
  favourites={favourities} 
  deleteFavourite={deleteFavourite} />
```

Only applying `favourites` will mean it's equal to `true` rather than the array in the state that you have.

Comment: can you `console.log(favourites)` and see if it's an array ?

Comment: The app now renders but `Shortlist` no longer works.  I get the error `filterUpdate is not a function`.  I also see error in console that  `'newSet' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars`

Comment: remember to go through and change all the standalone props. I can still see this: `<Search filterVal filterUpdate />` when it should be `<Search filterVal={filterText} filterUpdate={filterUpdate} />`

Comment: Thanks.  I did this and also fixed my error in `addFavourite` to `setFavourites(newSet)`  It works now.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: @ade1e no worries. good job converting it too. this is the right approach to take! if you get stuck again feel free to ask another question and I'll be happy to help :)

Comment: One thing I missed...  The clear search button is not working in my functional component  `{hasSearch && <button onClick={filterUpdate}>Clear Search</button>}`. How do I send an empty string as the `value` please?  I tried this but its not correct `filterUpdate(value={""})`.  Thanks so much.  I struggle with the React syntax.

Comment: what about just `filterUpdate('')`

Comment: I tried `filterUpdate('')` but this breaks the filter.

Comment: feel free to ask a new question with just the specific code and we can go from there :)

Comment: [Done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305276/search-functionality-no-longer-working-after-converting-from-react-class-to-func) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitely specify the props when you are passing it. to the child components

`<ShortList data={props.data} favourites={favourites} deleteFavourite={deleteFavourite} />`
Similar to the taglist

```
        <TagsList
          data={props.data}
          filter={filterText}
          favourites={favourites}
          addFavourite={addFavourite}
        />
```

Comment: Thanks I had added this after feedback from Red Baron but have marked your answer as useful too.